# What is login Credentials & How to provide it to Amazon app store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, amazon-appstore

I want to publish my android app to Amazon app store. In my app there is a firebase login system. Amazon app store is asking me for providing login Credentials. But I don't know what is this and how to provide it. Please help me. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQl9t.png)

Comment: I think ,in your app there is login screen and amazon tester cant do review your full app due to they have no login detail.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @Kabir. :)

Comment: How can I provide login details? The login screen has edittext1 for email Id & edittext2 for entering password